# WCFTestClient - how can I add username and pass?

Tags: security, service, wcf, wcf-security

I'm using the WCFTestClient to debug a service. This normally works like a charm. This particular service is using SSL and I need to pass the user name and password. I can right click and edit the config file, but I do not see a place where I can inject the user name and password. On the normal client app for this service, we programatically set the credentials, how do I do this using the tools WCFTEstClient or ServiceConfigurationEditor.  Anyone out there know how to do this? Here's how I do it in code.

```
_client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["name"];
_client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pass"];
```

Thanks for any help.
Cheers,
~ck in San Diego

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with the WCF Test Client. It's a fairly limited and simplistic tool - works great in simple scenarios, but stops fairly quickly.

If you need more features and abilities, you might want to look at [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org) which is a SOAP/web services testing tool and works quite well - the normal edition is free, too!

Comment: Just a comment for those using SoapUI so you don't have to look this up elsewhere - to pass credentials like the example given in the OP, you would set the WSS-PasswordType = PasswordText and then set the username and password all in the request properties window.

Comment: Whats the point of Microsoft making a tool, if it can not pass any credentials!?  This is ridiculous.   I've never heard of a real life WCF without credentials!

Comment: When using authentication in SoapUI, I couldn't get the domain field to work for me.  Instead I prepended the domain name to the username in the standard way: myDomain\MyUserName and left the Domain field empty.

Comment: One more thing... and since I was using an endpoint with basic bindings and not wss bindings I had to leave the wss-password type to none.